# Instantiated COM Component gets invalid after leaving method (but not its scope)

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-xe2, reference-counting

I am currently testing two external COM components. I have big issue with one of them, but I cannot really find reason behind such behavior. Let me provide some example.

```
const
  CLASS_SomeClas: TGUID = '{SomeGUID}';
type

ISomeInterface = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{SomeGUID}']
  function SomeMethod(const AInput: WideString): WideString; safecall;
end;

TWrappingClass = class(TObject)
strict private
  FInstance: ISomeInterface;
  procedure CreateInstance;
public
  procedure DoYourActualJob;
end;

procedure TWrappingClass.CreateInstance;
begin
  FInstance := CreateComObject(CLASS_SomeClass) as ISomeInterface;
  dbg(FInstance._AddRef); // Debugs 3
  dbg(FInstance._AddRef); // Debugs 4
  dbg(FInstance.Release); // Debugs 3
  dbg(FInstance._AddRef); // Debugs 4
  FInstance.SomeMethod(''); //Runs as expected
end;

procedure TWrappingClass.DoYourActualJob;
begin
  CreateInstance;
  dbg(FInstance._AddRef); //Debugs -1!
  FInstance.SomeMethod(''); //AV
end;
```

As provided with example instance gets invalid after it leaves `CreateInstance` method. Component is designed to work with many sequential calls of `SomeMethod` and it does work when called inside single method.
Could someone give me clue what is actually happening there, why my instance gets invalid? Is it problem with my code, with Delphi or with component's code? When I change the implementation of `TWrappingClass` to another vendor (that is I change both `ISomeInterface` and `CLASS_SomeClass`) then everything works fine.

**EDIT:**
Behaviour does not change when I don't even call `SomeMethod`. That is after I leave `CreateInstance`, call to `_AddRef` returns -1. Component I am testing is here [CadEditorX](http://cadsofttools.com/products/cadeditorx/download/) Probably I am not allowed to attach the OCX without violating its license.

Comment: Is there any way for us to reproduce this? There appear to be no problems in the code in the Q.

Comment: The only possibly way this could be happening is if `FInstance.SomeMethod()` is decrementing the instance's refcount internally to the point where the instance frees itself.  That implies that the COM object is likely buggy for violating refcount semantics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau as I stated in Q sequential calls work and they do not violate refcount semantics. I can call `SomeMethod` as many times as I want as long as I do it in the same scope...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan @RemyLebeau, Please see updated question. I even do not have to call `SomeMethod`. I also provided reference to component.

Comment: Again, the problem is not in the code presented here. You need to contact the component vendor.

Comment: For me it does not look like problem with component either. It's no difference for it in what context it's called isn't it?

Comment: I presume that you put that to the test by trying this code with a different COM object. One that is known to be good.

Comment: Sure I did, as stated in Q. But I still cannot imagine any bug in component that could cause that.

Comment: @MichalSzczygiel: if you can reproduce the problem using another COM object (the Win32 API is full of them!), or even without using any external COM object at all, just write your own interfaced object in your code instead, then it is a compiler bug. But if you can reproduce the problem using only this specific COM object and no other, then the COM object is at fault, and you have to contact the vendor. Considering that Delphi has natively supported COM and interface refcounting for over a decade without issue, this is not likely to be a compiler bug.

Comment: It's easy to imagine a bug that would cause this. A badly written component could implement reference counting incorrectly. It could simply destroy itself whenever `Release` is called, irrespective of how many references had been taken.

Comment: This is not the case here. When I call `_Release` it works fine (ie. returns correct value). As soon as I leave `CreateInstance`, `_Release` returns -1. And still leaving `CreateInstance` does not call `_Release`, as scope of variable is object's instance.

Comment: Clearly the component is broken. Eventually you will come to understand that. You should replicate the call sequence from an environment that doesn't do auto ref counting. E.g. C++. Remember to do the same as delphi does. Create IUnknown and then qiuery interface.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't find it clear. From what I have provided it's not possible to make conclusion that reference counting is broken inside the component. I have updated code with `Release` call.

Comment: Do the experiment with a C++ compiler. Also step through the Delphi program under the CPU debugger. Need to do that to pick up the implicit locals. I guess if you can't accept that the problem is not with Delphi then you are wasting your time here. All you can do is submit a QC report.

Comment: It's not the problem of accepting/not accepting things. I am trying to understand underlying behavior. It just don't seem to be problem with reference counting (see the code, and calls to `_AddRef` and `Release`). I have tried the same method call chain without `CreateInstance`(I put it's code in the place of call) and code works fine. I will try the same in other environment. Anyway thank you for your effort. I find CPU debugger advice useful.

Comment: You need to understand the issue with the temporary local introduced by the use of as on a function return value.

Comment: I have tested equivalent code in Delphi 7 and VS 2013. In Delphi 7 it fails the same way. In C++ however it works fine. I will try to debug CPU disassembly, but need to do some research in the area.

Comment: I guess you'd need to show the C++ code

Comment: I edited some code into my answer to try to explain what I mean about the hidden local IUnknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state clearly in the question that the erroneous behaviour only occurs with one specific COM object. Given this fact, and that Delphi's COM reference counting is known to work correctly, the only reasonable conclusion is that the fault lies in this specific COM object.

Your only recourse of action is to contact the vendor of this COM object and file a bug report with them.

---

One thing to look at, with a view to a possible work around, is how you are creating the object. You use `CreateComObject`. This receives a class ID and returns `IUnknown`. It calls `CoCreateInstance` passing the class ID, and requesting the `IUnknown` interface. You then need to query for your interface, `ISomeInterface`. So your code looks like this:

```
var
  iunk: IUnknown;
  intf: ISomeInteface;
....
CoCreateInstance(ClassID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
  IUnknown, iunk);
iunk.QueryInterface(ISomeInterface, intf);
```

The fact that you have two interface variables, one `IUnknown` and one `ISomeInterface` explains why you see the reference count that you do. Now, you might think that you only have one interface variable, but that's not the case. There are two, only one of them is an implicit local. You can see this by looking at the compiled code and stepping through under the debugger.

This code:

```
procedure TWrappingClass.CreateInstance;
begin
  FInstance := CreateComObject(CLASS_SomeClass) as ISomeInterface;
end;
```

is compiled as if it were this (ignoring error checking):

```
procedure TWrappingClass.CreateInstance;
var
  iunk: IUnknown;
begin
  iunk := CreateComObject(CLASS_SomeClass);
  try
    FInstance := CreateComObject(CLASS_SomeClass) as ISomeInterface;
  finally
    iunk := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Perhaps the COM component cannot handle the call to `Release` made on its `IUnknown` interface.

So, you could try to work around this by using `CoCreateInstance` instead of `CreateComObject`. Pass `ISomeInterface` as the `riid` parameter.

```
OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_SomeClass, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER 
  or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, ISomeInterface, FInstance));
```

Comment: Question: Will casting a com object to an interface get a reference to something other than the object iself? I seem to recall that if you did interface delegation in Delphi, casting an object to a delegated interface would increase the reference count for the interface, but not care one bit about the object in play, which meant you had a reference to something that was no longer in play. This just a stupid question though as it has been years since I did a lot of Delphi work, I just recall being in the same position, casting an object to an interface and losing the actual object.

Comment: @Lasse This is COM rather than Delphi. Behind the scenes, however it is implemented, all interfaces that are queried from a specific IUnknown have to share a lifetime.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can confirm that it is indeed some nasty bug in component. After getting instance through `CoCreateInstance` with `IID_ISgCADEditor` all works fine. But when I use `CoCreateInstance` with `IID_IUnknown` and then `QueryInterface` for the `IID_ISgCADEditor`, then it is broken. Sorry for not believing you at the beginning. But now I do have workaround and I have real arguments to the vendor, not just "it does not work for me". Sadly I can give you +1 only once.

Comment: Good. I'm glad I wasn't going mad!